# Python code not running, do I need to reinstall python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So when I'm trying to run this code. As you can see it asks for a number as an input.

```
print('How old is Vini?')
number= 17
guess= int(input('enter a number'))
if guess== number:
    print('Bravo Vini is 17')
elif guess < number:
    print('Vini is older than '+guess)
elif guess > number:
    print('Vini younger than '+guess)
```

Now if the number is equal to 17 it executes but if the number is higher or lower it gives me this error:

When the number is higher:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ervin\Desktop\loja.py", line 9, in <module>
    print('Vini younger than '+guess)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

When the number is lower:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ervin\Desktop\loja.py", line 7, in <module>
    print('Vini is older than '+guess)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: don't mind the title ( do I need to reinstall python?
), I just needed the website to accept the question.

Comment: Why would your first consideration be to reinstall python rather than investigating the error message?

Comment: `print('Vini younger than '+ str(guess))`

Comment: `print('Vini is older than '+guess)`=>`print('Vini is older than '+str(guess))` (dirty, but works)

Comment: See above.. and fix the title to avoid an excessive number of reactionary downvotes. Because the answer is: ***No**, you should fix your code*.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to `print('Vini is older than', guess)` than use conversion and concatenation.

Comment: also, reboot your computer, just in case this will fix it: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=it+crowd+have+you+tried+turning+it+off+and+on+again

Comment: you don't need to reinstall python, you need to _rewrite_ python so you can add strings with integers like in Javaaaaah

Comment: @Mangohero1: I don't believe that applies. The title is poor, but the question meets everything mentioned in the "itsnotworking" link.

Comment: @Mangohero1 Chill out dude. I mean, I can clearly see that you cannot wait until someone who's new posts a question and you can jump in to post that  but... come on, show some maturity :)

Comment: Weeellll I guess that was a little insensitive. But! I didn't quite post it like that!

Comment: no worries, anyway my problem was solved :P so thanks to all of you for taking your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `guess` to a string for the `print` statements to work, try writing `+ str(guess)` instead of `+ guess`.

Comment: Your method works. But what if I want the guess to be an integer?

Comment: @ErsonCokaj `str(guess)` doesn't permanently change `guess` into an string, it's only used as a string for that occurence, in this case in the `print`, it won't have any side effects

Comment: @NickA ok thanks, very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

In statement `print('Vini is older than '+guess)` you are trying to concatenate a string('Vini is older than ') with an integer(17) which is wrong hence the error that you are getting.

Use

```
 print('Vini is older than '+str(guess))
```

`str(guess)` converts the integer to a string.
Now you are concatenating two strings which is valid.